# PHP Find Coordinates between two points

Tags: php, math, loops, coordinates

simple question here. Lets say I have two points:

```
point 1

x = 0
y = 0


point 2

x = 10
y = 10
```

How would i find out all the coordinates inbetween that programmatically, assuming there is a strait line between two points... so the above example would return:

```
0,0
1,1
2,2
3,3
...
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Not to nitpick but there are an infinite number of points between any two points on a plane. If you mean integral points, thats different, but your minimum step will dictate how many maximal points there are.

Comment: I suggest you use a better example, as this makes the line equation y=x which is not the usual case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for all your help but non of the answers posted worked how i wanted it to. For example, lets say my points were:

0, 0

0, 10

There would only be a start and a finish coordinate... it wouldnt find the ones inbetween.

Maybe i did something wrong :S but i came up with my own solution:

```
// Points
$p1 = array(
    'x' => 50,
    'y' => 50
);

$p2 = array(
    'x' => 234,
    'y' => 177
);

// Work out distances
$pxd = $p2['x'] - $p1['x'];
$pyd = $p2['y'] - $p1['y'];

// Find out steps
$steps = max($p1['x'], $p1['y'], $p2['x'], $p2['y']);

$coords = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $steps; ++ $i) {
    $coords[] = array(
        'x' => round($p1['x'] += $pxd / $steps),
        'y' => round($p1['y'] += $pyd / $steps)
    );
}

print_r($coords);
```

Comment: You found one of the two exceptions where the solution y = a + bx does not work. The reason is that the slope b would be infinite (as division by 0 is not defined, and x1 - x2 is 0). 

Your solution has drawbacks, though: you only calculate discrete values for the upper right quadrant (positive x and y). And the steps are arbitrarily defined by the largest coordinate: take (20,0) and (21,1): there will be 21 steps, while (0,5) and (1,3) will result in only 3 steps. 

Try using $steps = max($pdx, $pdy) instead.

Comment: Making the change to $steps works inconsistently. Plug in 3,3 and 0,5 and the code returns only two points: 2,4 and 0,5. It misses an intervening point along x=1 with either y=4 or y=5, either of which would be acceptable I imagine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find the slope of the line first:

```
m = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2)
```

Then you need to find the equation of the line:

```
y = mx + b
```

In your example you we get:

```
y = 1x + b
0 = 1(0) + b
```

or

```
y = x
```

To get all of the coordinates you simply need to plug in all values x1 -> x2. In PHP this entire thing looks something like:

```
// These are in the form array(x_cord, y_cord)
$pt1 = array(0, 0);
$pt2 = array(10, 10);
$m = ($pt1[1] - $pt2[1]) / ($pt1[0] - $pt2[0]);
$b = $pt1[1] - $m * $pt1[0];

for ($i = $pt1[0]; $i <= $pt2[0]; $i++)
    $points[] = array($i, $m * $i + $b);
```

This will of course give you the coordinates for all points that fall on integer values of X, and not "all coordinates" between the two points.

Comment: +1, Your code seems to do exactly what I had wanted my code to originally do, its cleaner and looks more like a solid solution.

Comment: you beat me to it. anyways i leave my algo up for those who want.

Comment: Testing for a vertical line is left as an exercise for the user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the line equation, y = mx + c
2. Put (0,0) and and (10,10) to get two equations and solve to get values of m and c. (you will be able to find the direct equations to get m and c somewhere).
3. Then create a loop to start from x = x1 (0) till x = x2 (10)
4. Using y=mx+c, get the value of y (now that you know m and c)

Answer (score 1):

To generate all the lattice points (points with integral coordinates) on the segment between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), where x1, x2, y1, and y2 are integers:

```
function gcd($a,$b) {
    // implement the Euclidean algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor of two integers, always returning a non-negative value
    $a = abs($a);
    $b = abs($b);
    if ($a == 0) {
        return $b;
    } else if ($b == 0) {
        return $a;
    } else {
        return gcd(min($a,$b),max($a,$b) % min($a,$b));
    }
}

function lattice_points($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2) {
    $delta_x = $x2 - $x1;
    $delta_y = $y2 - $y1;
    $steps = gcd($delta_x, $delta_y);
    $points = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $steps; $i++) {
        $x = $x1 + $i * $delta_x / $steps;
        $y = $y1 + $i * $delta_y / $steps;
        $points[] = "({$x},{$y})";
    }
    return $points;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work consistently. Given (3,3,0,5) it only returns 3,3 and 0,5 but none of the intervening points. Works correctly with (3,3,0,6) which is a perfect "45 degree line" but doesn't work well along other slopes.

Comment: @DonJones: There aren't any lattice points—that is, points for which both coordinates are integers—on the line segment between (3,3) and (0,5).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler algorithm would be, find the midpoint by averaging out the coordinates, repeat until you're done. Just wanted to point out because no one did.