# How can I calculate the points along a line in PHP?

Tags: php, math, geometry

I apologize if this is overly simple, but I'm the furthest thing possible from a math major, and I have trouble reducing abstract formulas into workable code. I know the formula for a line, but turning it into code is making my head spin. And stressing out my code debugger.

Given a 2D grid coordinate system, I need to be able to specify a starting point X1,Y1 and an ending point X2,Y2 and calculate a list of all grid cells directly on a line between those two points.

So if...

```
X1,Y1 = 3,3
X2,Y2 = 0,5
```

I would want to calculate an array of points

```
3,3
2,4
1,4
0,5
```

Or something like that. It's also kind of important that I be able to list these points in order - so as above, I'm starting with the origin X,Y and moving toward the destination X,Y.

(And no, this isn't homework - I've seen that asked for a lot of other math questions here, so I'll get it out of the way up front. Maybe if I'd done this as homework 25 years ago I wouldn't need to ask now!)

I did find [PHP Find Coordinates between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441362/php-find-coordinates-between-two-points) which seems to talk around the solution, but the comments indicate that the "accepted" answer isn't complete.

Many thanks.

Comment: The solution in the link you showed seems to be pretty decent. At least it should give you a good idea on how to solve it. Even if it's not complete, I grasp his idea and think you can build on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your best bet might be [Bresenham's algorithm for drawing a line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), except instead of plotting the points you'll be capturing the x,y values.

Comment: That was it. Punching in "bresenham's PHP" into the Goog got me to http://alex.moutonking.com/wordpress/?p=44, which is a PHP implementation that appears to work.

Comment: I'm going to include the final PHP code below as an answer, although since you put me on to it I'm leaving yours as "the" answer. Bresenham was it - I just needed to cobble an implementation, which someone else might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want whole-number coordinates, since that's what you listed in the example. But note that this is not necessarily the case for any arbitrary set of (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). My answer here will give you whole-number x-coordinates only.

I would use the two-point form of the linear equation.
yi = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(xi-x1) + y1
where (xi,yi) are the points you are looking for.

```
for ($xi=$x1; $xi<$x2; $xi++) {
  $yi = ($y2-$y1)/($x2-$x1)*($xi-$x1) + $y1
  echo $xi + "," + $yi
}
```

Just make sure you have `$x1 < $x2` before you run the above code.

A more complicated situation arises when you draw a line between two arbitrary points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and you want to output the list of squares (grid cells) intersected by that line.

Comment: That more complicated situation is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is particularly elegant, but here's how I would do it:

```
function getLinePoints( $startPoint, $endPoint ){
    $totalSteps = max( abs( $startPoint[0] - $endPoint[0] ), abs( $startPoint[1] - $endPoint[1] ) );
    if ( $totalSteps == 0 ){
      return $startPoint;
    }
    $xStep = ( $endPoint[0] - $startPoint[0] ) / $totalSteps;
    $yStep = ( $endPoint[1] - $startPoint[1] ) / $totalSteps;

    $points[] = $currentPoint = $startPoint;
    for( $step = 0; $step < $totalSteps; $step++ ){
        $currentPoint[0] += $xStep;
        $currentPoint[1] += $yStep;
        $points[] = array( round( $currentPoint[0], 0 ), round( $currentPoint[1], 0 ) );
    }
    return $points;
}

$pointA = array( 3, 3 );
$pointB = array( 0, 5 );
$points = getLinePoints( $pointA, $pointB );
```

This takes the following steps:

1. Get the total whole number of points you'll have to traverse horizontally or vertically.
2. Calculates how far you'll have to travel horizontally or vertically at each step.
3. Constructs an array of points with coordinates rounded to whole numbers.

Return value should be:

```
Array(
    Array( 3, 3 ),
    Array( 2, 4 ),
    Array( 1, 4 ),
    Array( 0, 5 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for more specifics, here's a PHP function that will always return the points with the first array element as the origin and the last as the destination. This is tested and working, and is an adaptation of http://alex.moutonking.com/wordpress/?p=44.

```
function bresenham($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $guaranteeEndPoint=true) {
    $xBegin = $x1;
    $yBegin = $y1;
    $xEnd = $x2;
    $yEnd = $y2;
    $dots = array();

    $steep = abs($y2 - $y1) &gt; abs($x2 - $x1);

    if ($steep) {
        $tmp = $x1;
        $x1 = $y1;
        $y1 = $tmp;
        $tmp = $x2;
        $x2 = $y2;
        $y2 = $tmp;
    }

    if ($x1 > $x2) {
        $tmp = $x1;
        $x1 = $x2;
        $x2 = $tmp;
        $tmp = $y1;
        $y1 = $y2;
        $y2 = $tmp;
    }

    $deltax = floor($x2 - $x1);
    $deltay = floor(abs($y2 - $y1));
    $error = 0;
    $deltaerr = $deltay / $deltax;
    $y = $y1;
    $ystep = ($y1 < $y2) ? 1 : -1;

    for ($x = $x1; $x < $x2; $x++) {
        $dots[] = $steep ? array($y, $x) : array($x, $y);       
        $error += $deltaerr;        
        if ($error >= 0.5) {
            $y += $ystep;
            $error -= 1;
        }
    } 

    if ($guaranteeEndPoint) {
    if ((($xEnd - $x) * ($xEnd - $x) + ($yEnd - $y) * ($yEnd - $y)) < (($xBegin - $x) * ($xBegin - $x) + ($yBegin - $y) * ($yBegin - $y))) {
        $dots[] = array($xEnd, $yEnd);
    } else 
        $dots[] = array($xBegin, $yBegin);
    }

    if ($dots[0][0] != $xBegin and $dots[0][1] != $yBegin) {
        return array_reverse($dots);        
    } else {
        return $dots;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you re looking for interpolation methods, check this : http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/ (what u need is linear interpolation)