# PHP get all co-ordinates between 4 sets of co-ordinates

Tags: php, math

I was having a look at this solution - [PHP Find Coordinates between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441362/php-find-coordinates-between-two-points)

I tried the code and it worked. Though the code gets the list of co-ordinates of a diagonal line.

```
$p1 = array(
    'x' => 0,
    'y' => 0
);

$p2 = array(
    'x' => 10,
    'y' => 10
);

// Work out distances
$pxd = $p2['x'] - $p1['x'];
$pyd = $p2['y'] - $p1['y'];

// Find out steps
$steps = max($p1['x'], $p1['y'], $p2['x'], $p2['y']);

$coords = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $steps; ++ $i) {
    $coords[] = array(
        'x' => round($p1['x'] += $pxd / $steps),
        'y' => round($p1['y'] += $pyd / $steps)
    );
}

print_r($coords);
```

In the above code one gets 10 co-ordinates i.e.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 1 [y] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [x] => 2 [y] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [x] => 3 [y] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [x] => 4 [y] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [x] => 5 [y] => 5 ) [5] => Array ( [x] => 6 [y] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [x] => 7 [y] => 7 ) [7] => Array ( [x] => 8 [y] => 8 ) [8] => Array ( [x] => 9 [y] => 9 ) [9] => Array ( [x] => 10 [y] => 10 ) )
```

The above is a diagonal line.

I'd like to get 100 co-ordinates i.e. (1,1),(1,2),(1,3), (1,4)...... (7,10),(8,10),)(9,10),(10,10).

I am not sure how to mathematically go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two loops; one for the 'x' axis, and one for the 'y' axis

So something more like (untested):

```
for ($x = $p1['x']; $x < $p2['x']; ++ $x) {
    for ($y = $p1['y']; $y < $p2['y']; ++ $y) {
        $coords[] = array(
           'x' => round($x),
           'y' => round($y)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a stupid and banal question but I am stuck. Rather than having `print_r` how do I echo each co-ordinate `x , y` rather than `Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 1 [y] => 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested for loop.

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){

  for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){

     $coords[] = array('x'=>$i,'y'=>$j);

  }

}
```