# Query set of points in AREA within distance from line segment

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

I have line segments and points stored in a db. How would I query the db in order to retrieve the all the points that are within a certain distance of multiple line segments.
The purpose is that when the user clicks on a path (road), all the objects that are within a distance from the path should be highlighted.

Thank you.

**Update:**
Example... 
I have a path that goes from (0,0) to (0, 10). The program should find and highlight all objects within x-distance of this path. 
Suppose that the x-distance is "2"... then, the program should highlight all objects within the rectangle (0,2)(10,-2). Basically, this is the same as finding all objects with a proximity to the line (not just a single point).

It is easy when the line is horizontal... But I don't know how to solve for all cases, including then the line may be a slope.

**Update:** The points are stored in a large database, so I cannot check each and every one of them for the proximity. I'm trying to find  a way to retrieve only the ones that are close enough without overlapping requests too much... Once they are retrieved, I can refine the search by using the method described in "distance between a point and a line segment". (I think!)
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Find Coordinates between two points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441362/php-find-coordinates-between-two-points)

Comment: Do you have some code, or an example of how the data is stored?

Comment: each row in the database has 3 fields: id, x_axis, y_axis.. all integers

Comment: Everything you'd ever want to know about this seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment

Comment: Are there any assumptions you can make to simplify the math? Do the line segments all have a similar length? Is the maximum distance the user can enter always greater than the segment lengths? Are the routes more or less straight?

Comment: the distance the user can enter is always greater than the segment lengths. Routes are not straight.. The best I could come up with following your advice was dividing the map into grids, and only querying the database for points in grid cells that do not overlap with the search square from the previous segment.

Comment: So did you end up using any of the javascript code, or did you find a specialised database solution?

Comment: In the end I wrote a variation of Bresenham's line drawing Algorithm, and wherever the line intersected with the side of a grid, I added the adjacent grids to an array. Then, made the request to the DB selecting all points that would fall within on those grids... After getting the results, I used your distancetoLineSegment() function on for each of the results.. I chose this solution bc there are millions of points and couldn't check each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the distance from point p to line segment v,w. (based on this question: [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)). You'll have to run through all your points and calculate the distance to all your line segments to find the ones close enough to the route.
If it's too slow, you'll have to make some kind of simplification that doesn't need square roots.

```js
function distanceToLineSegment(p, v, w)
{
    var len2 = dist2(v, w);
    if (len2 == 0) return Math.sqrt(dist2(p, v));
    var s = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / len2;
    if (s < 0) return Math.sqrt(dist2(p, v));
    if (s > 1) return Math.sqrt(dist2(p, w));
    var i = {x: v.x + s * (w.x - v.x), y: v.y + s * (w.y - v.y)};
    return Math.sqrt(dist2(p, i));

    function dist2(p, q) {
        return Math.pow(p.x - q.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - q.y, 2);
    }
}

alert(distanceToLineSegment({x:2, y:3}, {x:-1, y:4}, {x:3, y:8}));
```

This is a somewhat optimized implementation that checks a list of points against a route.
The points to check are stored as an array `far[]` of points with x and y values and an id string. There is a second, initially empty array `close[]` into which the points are moved if they are found to be close to the route, so that points aren't checked twice. These two arrays are stored in an object `points`, so that they can be passed by reference between the functions, instead of constantly being copied. I've also removed the square root functions for efficiency.
Further optimization is probably possible by changing the distance calculation to a coarser approximation (maybe using rectangles) instead of a mathematically correct one.

```js
function isCloseToRoute(points, route, distance) {
    var distance2 = Math.pow(distance, 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        isCloseToLineSegment(points, route[i], route[i + 1], distance2);
    }

    function isCloseToLineSegment(points, v, w, distance2) {
        for (var i = points.far.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (distanceToLineSegment2(points.far[i], v, w) <= distance2) {
                points.close.push(points.far.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    function distanceToLineSegment2(p, v, w) {
        var len2 = dist2(v, w);
        if (len2 == 0) return dist2(p, v);
        var q = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / len2;
        if (q < 0) return dist2(p, v);
        if (q > 1) return dist2(p, w);
        var i = {x: v.x + q * (w.x - v.x), y: v.y + q * (w.y - v.y)};
        return dist2(p, i);
    
        function dist2(p, q) {
            return Math.pow(p.x - q.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - q.y, 2);
        }
    }
}

var points = {close: [], far: [{x: 1, y: 0, id: "A"}, 
                               {x: 2, y: 1, id: "B"}, 
                               {x:-1, y: 8, id: "C"}, 
                               {x:-3, y: 4, id: "D"}]};
var route = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 2}, {x:-1, y: 4}, {x: 2, y: 8}];

isCloseToRoute(points, route, 2);
alert(points.close.length + " points found near route");
for (i in points.close) console.log(points.close[i].id);
```

If you divide your map into a grid, you can use isCloseToRoute() to check which grid cells are near the route. It will return a list of grid cells which have a key like "6,4"; if you give each point in your database a key that indicates in which grid cells it's located, you can look them up without having to do any math on the coordinates.
You make an input object just like when checking a list of points, fill the far[] array with the center points of the grid cells, and run isCloseToRoute() on it with a distance of (distance + gridSize*sqrt(2)/2).
In the example, the map is a 1000 x 1000 square, divided into 64 grid cells each sized 125 x 125.

```js
function isCloseToRoute(points, route, distance) {
    var distance2 = Math.pow(distance, 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        isCloseToLineSegment(points, route[i], route[i + 1], distance2);
    }

    function isCloseToLineSegment(points, v, w, distance2) {
        for (var i = points.far.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (distanceToLineSegment2(points.far[i], v, w) <= distance2) {
                points.close.push(points.far.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    function distanceToLineSegment2(p, v, w) {
        var len2 = dist2(v, w);
        if (len2 == 0) return dist2(p, v);
        var q = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / len2;
        if (q < 0) return dist2(p, v);
        if (q > 1) return dist2(p, w);
        var i = {x: v.x + q * (w.x - v.x), y: v.y + q * (w.y - v.y)};
        return dist2(p, i);
    
        function dist2(p, q) {
            return Math.pow(p.x - q.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - q.y, 2);
        }
    }
}

var route = [{x: 210, y: 190}, {x: 820, y: 480}, {x:530, y: 470}, {x: 440, y: 760}];
var distance = 100;
var mapSize = 1000;
var gridSize = 125;
var gridCells = Math.floor(mapSize / gridSize);
var grid = {close: [], far: []};

for (x = 0; x < gridCells; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < gridCells; y++) {
        grid.far[y * (gridCells) + x] = {x: (x + 0.5) * gridSize, 
                                         y: (y + 0.5) * gridSize, 
                                       key: x + "," + y};
    }
}

isCloseToRoute(grid, route, distance + 0.707107 * gridSize);
alert(grid.close.length + " grid cells near route");
for (i in grid.close) console.log(grid.close[i].key);
```

I've optimized isCloseToRoute() a bit more. The example runs a test with 1000 random points checked against a 1000-segment random route.

```js
function isCloseToRoute(points, route, distance) {
    var distance2 = Math.pow(distance, 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
        isCloseToLineSegment(route[i], route[i + 1]);
    }

    function isCloseToLineSegment(v, w) {
        var len2 = distanceToPoint2(v, w);
        var lenX = w.x - v.x, lenY = w.y - v.y;
        for (var i = points.far.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (distanceToLineSegment2(points.far[i]) <= distance2) {
                points.near.push(points.far.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            }
        }

        function distanceToLineSegment2(p) {
          if (len2 == 0) return distanceToPoint2(p, v);   // enable if zero-length segments are possible
            var q = ((p.x - v.x) * lenX + (p.y - v.y) * lenY) / len2;
            if (q < 0) return distanceToPoint2(p, v);
            if (q > 1) return distanceToPoint2(p, w);
            var r = {x: v.x + q * lenX, y: v.y + q * lenY};
            return distanceToPoint2(p, r);
        }

        function distanceToPoint2(p, q) {
            return Math.pow(p.x - q.x, 2) + Math.pow(p.y - q.y, 2);
        }
    }
}

// generate random test data
var points = {near: [], far: [{x: 500, y: 500}]};
var route = [{x: 200, y: 200}];
var distance = 100;
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    points.far[i] = {x: Math.random() * 1000, y: Math.random() * 1000};
    route[i] = {x: route[i - 1].x + 3 * Math.random() - 1, y: route[i - 1].y + 3 * Math.random() - 1};
}

var t = new Date().getTime();
isCloseToRoute(points, route, distance);
t = new Date().getTime() - t;
alert(points.near.length + " points found near route.\n(1000 points checked against 1000 segments in " + t + " ms)");
for (i in points.near) console.log(points.near[i].x + "," + points.near[i].y);
```

Comment: That is very helpful. I will use this. However, performance-wise, the obstacle of how to retrieve the points from the db so that only the points that are close enough to the path be submitted to this operation.

Comment: Maybe you could divide your map into squares and organize the db in these squares, and only load the points from the squares that are close to the route?

Comment: @JeanAlesi I've expanded it into a basic route-checking function, with a few simple optimizations. I have no idea whether this is efficient enough for the amount of data it'll be handling.

Comment: Yes.. I think that's a good idea. I am trying with a grid. I was wondering though, if there is a specialized algorithm, as GPS services employ similar features.

Comment: The best way to store the points is probably not as a list, but as a space-partitioning tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Trees), e.g. the Quadtree, but I really don't know enough about this to make a recommendation.

Comment: I don't know which database system you're using, but most seem to have specific spatial database functions, according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_database_systems