# How to get an Array of points between 2 3d vectors

Tags: php, vector, 3d

Im looking for a way to get an array of points between 2 points that are 3d.

## What I’ve found

So far while looking ive not found anything that is 3d, when I look for 3d it only returns a bunch of things of `How to get distance between 2 points` And thats not what im looking for!

I have found 1 good one about 2d points - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441408/17281632)

However Ive found nothing about 3d, so sorry if this is duplicate.

Ive also tried search Stack Exchange Mathematics, and multiple other webpages, and still cant find anything that can answer my question.

## More Details

Im going to give an example so that its more clear what I am looking for. Say I have 2 3d vectors (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2). My points in this example will be `(0, 0, 0)` and `(10, 10, 10)`.

After I have run these through the function I would want it to return an array of points something like this:

```
[1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 2],
[3, 3, 3]
```

All the way up to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

I have now found the answer to my question above.

```php
function logPointsOnLine(array $point1, array $point2, int $points) {

  $vecs = [];
  
  $delX = $point2[0] - $point1[0];
  $delY = $point2[1] - $point1[1];
  $delZ = $point2[2] - $point1[2];

  for($i = 0; $i < $points; $i++) {
    $newX = $point1[0] + $delX / ($points - 1) * $i;
    $newY = $point1[1] + $delY / ($points - 1) * $i;
    $newZ = $point1[2] + $delZ / ($points - 1) * $i;
    array_push($vecs, array($newX, $newY, $newZ));
  }
}
```

If you want to run it one way you could do it is:

```php
$vec1 = array(10, 12, 32);
$vec2 = array(15, 60, 25);
$amt = 10;

$points = logPointsOnLine($vec1, $vec2, $amt);

print_r($points);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a 'for' loop?

```
function myFunction() {

    $arr = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
        $arr[] = array($i, $i, $i);
    }

    return $arr;
}

$myArr = myFunction();
```

The result will be an array with each key having an array value incremented.

you can use see complete array...

```
print_r($myArr);
```

Or each individual value by using its key value...

```
echo $myArr[0][2]
```

Comment: This works for `x=y` which is what I used in my example, which is my fault because in most cases it would not be that way, but I need one that would be global for 2 points that could be `(1, 30, 302)` and `(122, 20, -39)` aswell

Comment: Do you know any way that you can do this with points like that @JasonF ?